# Spree: Display brand name for product?

Tags: ruby, spree

I have been looking through the spree documentation and doing a lot of searching but I haven't got anything working.

The most relevant link I found was this...

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spree-user/HjQVI8eXuYI

I tried the different bits of code there but none of it worked I simply got errors like this

NoMethodError in Spree::Home#index

I simply want to display the brand name of a specific product, something like this...

" product.brand "

Some one pleas help me with this, there has to be some simple solution for this, I just want to show the dang brand name.

Comment: How did you implemented brands into your store? Via properties or taxons? which version of spree are you using?

Comment: I am using the latest version of spree, we just installed it last week, and we have not brought in any inventory just yet, I am simply working with the default inventory that spree comes with.

Comment: All I want to know is how to display a products brand name in code.

To display the products name I know I use  product.name 

How can I do the same for brand, I have tried a lot of combinations

Does something like product.brand  exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a property named **brand** and then simply display its value in **/views/spree/products/show.html.erb** like this:

```
<%= @product.property('brand')%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found using pluck was the cleanest and easiest way to add the brand name :

```
def brand 
  taxons.pluck(:name).last 
end
```

Comment: This assumes that `taxons` always returns the single brand taxon last, which is not expressed in the answer!